# Customising NavigationView - Adding dynamic headerView, Android Support Design Library

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport, navigationview

I tried the navigationView from the new android support design library. I want to have a dynamic headerview. Basically, my headerview will show something like quote of the day. I have like around 10 quotes and i want to randomly select a quote and display in a textview in the headerView. I also want to add onClick method for the headerView.

Right now, I don't see any possibilities of changing the headerview layout programmatically. Any suggestions to implement this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

first create header XML like **lay_header.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvThought"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

on your java file inflate this above header in a TextView. like

```
TextView headerView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.lay_header, null);
headerView.setText("Your_thoght");
```

Now add it as a HeaderView

```
navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navView);
navView.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

Thats it...

Answer (score 15):

After the new support library update (23.1.1),

You could do this -

Add the headerview in the `app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"` inside NavigationView.

Then, you can access it by,

```
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

or if you have multiple headers

```
navigationView.getHeaderCount()
```

Ref : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190226#c31

Answer (score 6):

```
TextView txt2;
txt2 = (TextView) navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main).findViewById(R.id.textView2);
txt2.setText("wow! It works like a charm");
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

create header layout take text view inside,

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/profile_email_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/profile_image"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/expand_account_box_indicator"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onSelectText"
                android:text="dhaval0122@gmail.com"
                android:textColor="@color/body_text_2_inverse"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />
```

in onCreate,

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_email_text)).setText("test");
```

create method `onSelectText` in your activity

```
public void onSelectText(View v){
        if(v.getId() == R.id.profile_email_text){
            Snackbar
                    .make(fab, "clicked on sub title", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            //.setAction(R.string.snackbar_action, myOnClickListener)
                    .show();
            drawer_layout.closeDrawers();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may add your custom header programmatically by calling `addHeaderView` on your navigationView, or define it in the layout file using `app:headerLayout="@layout/myheader"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findViewById()` to access header elements within the NavigationView. This works even if you've initialised the header with the headerLayout property e.g. `app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"`. You can then dynamically modify the header without any need to inflate or add a new header.

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {

...

if(mNavItemId == R.id.drawer_item_1)
{
  View headerView = mNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_header_root);
  // Test modifying the size of the header root element (FrameLayout)
  // when the first menu item is clicked.
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) headerView.getLayoutParams();
  p.height = p.height == 700 ? 400 : 700;
  headerView.setLayoutParams(p);
  return true;
}
...
```

**drawer_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="196dp"
android:background="@color/drawer_header_bg"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/drawer_header_root">
...
```

I think Dhawal is saying the same thing, but it wasn't super clear.

Answer (score 0):

My be this link will help you

[slimier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286109/change-design-support-navigation-view-header-title-programmatically/34015681#34015681)

```
final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

View headView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

((TextView) headView.findViewById(R.id.nav_title)).setText("New title");
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get navigationView.
`NavigationView navigationView =(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);`

Then header.
`View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0)`
Then textView.
`TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textView);`
And finally you can set the text you want to display.
`text.setText("Hello there");`