# Is there any way to control views inside NavigationView header?

Tags: android, navigationview

As the title says, I want to know if there is any way to control views inside the `NavigationView` header? (Except for adding or removing header.)

For example: In the header, I have a user avatar. By default, it displays a guest image, but after the user logs in, the real avatar will be showed.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Its up to you what you are inflating in header view.
You can take `ImageView` inside `LinearLayout` and change ImageDrawable dynamically .

Comment: Could you show more details, ex my header just with textview inside FrameLayout.

Comment: refer my this answer .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30660069/3544839 ...

Comment: in above link i change textview so you just take imageview and change drawable instead of setText of textview..

Comment: ah, i see your answer before. But as i mentioned (except for removing/adding header), i'm finding another way to do that. Maybe a way to get access to the header through the navigationview.

Comment: So for that you can use inflateHeaderView(int resID) of NavigationView. Which will give you View object in return so that you can access the full layout using view object

Comment: thanks for your help :)

Comment: Until now, the best answer is Moikhan at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621047/customising-navigationview-adding-dynamic-headerview-android-support-design-l/30660069#30660069

Comment: you can vote up there bro ...lolzzz

Comment: please check this answer for correct solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/33365230/3792198

Answer (score 59, accepted):

After updating your support library to version 23.1.1 or above,

You could do this -

```
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

or if you have multiple headers

```
navigationView.getHeaderCount()
```

Ref : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190226#c31

Answer (score 7):

Since i can not accept a comment as an answer. So, i repost Moinkhan' answer here:

first create header XML like lay_header.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvThought"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

on your java file inflate this above header in a TextView. like

```
TextView headerView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.lay_header, null);
headerView.setText("Your_thoght");
```

Now add it as a HeaderView

```
navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navView);
navView.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

Thats it...

You can also check it out at: [Customising NavigationView - Adding dynamic headerView, Android Support Design Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621047/customising-navigationview-adding-dynamic-headerview-android-support-design-l/30660069#30660069)

Many thanks!
And again, we need a function that allow user to accept a comment as answer!

Answer (score 1):

The other way to make this is using the method "inflateHeaderView()" of NavigationView object, like below (After using "setContentView()"):

```
View headerLayout = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.yours_nav_header_layout);
```

After this point you can use "headerLayout" to access custom views in your header layout, like below:

```
View cutomView = (TextView) headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.lay_sign_in);
```

In my case i'm using ButterKnife framework to inject View "navigationView" like this:

```
@Bind(R.id.nav_view) NavigationView navigationView;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }
```

Comment: This method is fine as long as the header is not already defined in the xml of navigationview . if so,  calling inflateheaderview adds an extra header in the side drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try find your view in your activity:

```
tvUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_username);
```

It works for me. My header layout is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My NavigationView in Activity Layout is:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"/>
```

And BTW, I came across problem when inflating LinearLayout, where layout params are not provided:

```
TextView headerView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.lay_header, null);
headerView.setText("Your_thoght");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You don't seem to reference the actuall TextView's ID. How would you differentiate or identify the actual TextView you want when you have more than one TextViews in the header layout?

I presume you would inflate it as a View then from the view you can get the TextView by id?

Comment: @Nerudo, well, it 's there in Header layout: android:id="@+id/tv_username". and reference it by ID findViewById(R.id.tv_username);