# Getting error in existing code after updating support repository to 23.1.0

Tags: android, android-support-library

When I am running my project using support libraries 23.0.0, I am not getting any error, but today when I updated my support repository to 23.1.0, the code of my activity is exactly same in both versions of using support libraries. I am getting the following error:

```
10-27 14:56:31.734 26271-26271/com.galleri5.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 14:56:31.734 26271-26271/com.galleri5.android E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.galleri5.android, PID: 26271
10-27 14:56:31.734 26271-26271/com.galleri5.android E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
10-27 14:56:31.734 26271-26271/com.galleri5.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)
10-27 14:56:31.734 26271-26271/com.galleri5.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
10-27 14:56:31.734 26271-26271/com.galleri5.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.galleri5.android.activities.HomeActivity$3.success(HomeActivity.java:155)
10-27 14:56:31.734 26271-26271/com.galleri5.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.galleri5.android.activities.HomeActivity$3.success(HomeActivity.java:151)
10-27 14:56:31.734 26271-26271/com.galleri5.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(CallbackRunnable.java:45)
10-27 14:56:31.734 26271-26271/com.galleri5.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-27 14:56:31.734 26271-26271/com.galleri5.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-27 14:56:31.734 26271-26271/com.galleri5.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-27 14:56:31.734 26271-26271/com.galleri5.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
10-27 14:56:31.734 26271-26271/com.galleri5.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-27 14:56:31.734 26271-26271/com.galleri5.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-27 14:56:31.734 26271-26271/com.galleri5.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
10-27 14:56:31.734 26271-26271/com.galleri5.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
10-27 14:56:32.605 26271-26342/com.galleri5.android E/GAv4: Successfully bound to service but never got onServiceConnected callback
```

Here is the code of my Activity:

package com.galleri5.android.activities;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.galleri5.android.Galleri5Application;
import com.galleri5.android.R;
import com.galleri5.android.adapters.FeedAdapter;
import com.galleri5.android.api.FeedAPI;
import com.galleri5.android.api.UserAPI;
import com.galleri5.android.models.FeedItem;
import com.galleri5.android.models.User;
import com.galleri5.android.utils.CircleTransform;
import com.galleri5.android.utils.SourceType;
import com.galleri5.android.utils.TinyDB;
import com.galleri5.android.utils.Utils;
import com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.RequestInterceptor;
import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.RetrofitError;
import retrofit.client.OkClient;
import retrofit.client.Response;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    FeedAdapter adapter;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    String token;
    TinyDB tinyDB;
    int SELECT_FILE = 1;
    static int radius = Utils.dpToPx(90);
    FloatingActionMenu fab;
    List<FeedItem> list;
    int commentIndex, r;
    static boolean commented;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                request.addHeader("Authorization", "Token " + token);
            }
        };

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setEndpoint(API)
                .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .build();

        FeedAPI feedAPI = restAdapter.create(FeedAPI.class);
        feedAPI.getFeed(new Callback<List<FeedItem>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<FeedItem> feedItems, Response response) {
                Log.i("Retrofit Info", "Success");
                Log.i("Data", feedItems.toString());
                list = feedItems;
                adapter = new FeedAdapter(HomeActivity.this, list);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.i("Retrofit Error", "Feed Failed");
            }
        });

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#e2b509"));
        }

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        assert ab != null;

        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.feed_ic_menu);

        // Find our drawer view
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.feed_ic_menu);

        final Typeface opensans = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
        final ImageView navProfile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.navProfilePic);
        final TextView username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        final TextView karma = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView89);



> UserAPI userAPI = restAdapter.create(UserAPI.class);
>             userAPI.getFeed("-1", "json", new Callback<User>() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void success(final User user, Response response) {
>                     Log.i("USER", "User API successful");
>                     Picasso.with(HomeActivity.this)
>                             .load(user.getDpUrl())
>                             .resize(radius, radius)
>                             .centerCrop()
>                             .transform(new CircleTransform())
>                             .into(navProfile);
>     
>                     username.setText(user.getFirstName());
>                     username.setTypeface(opensans);
>     
>                     karma.setText(String.format("%s Karma Points", Integer.toString(user.getKarma())));
>                     karma.setTypeface(opensans);
>                 }
>     
>                 @Override
>                 public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
>                     Log.i("USER", "User Profile Failed");
>                 }
>             });


        // Find our drawer view
        NavigationView nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Setup drawer view
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        });

        fab = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setClosedOnTouchOutside(true);

        findViewById(R.id.fabFacebook).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SourceType type = new SourceType(true, false, false);
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, FbImageSelectionActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.fabAlbum).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SourceType type = new SourceType(false, false, true);
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                        SELECT_FILE);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.imageView129).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    private void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {

        Intent intent;

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                break;
            case R.id.nav_studio:
                showUserProfile("-1");
                break;
            case R.id.nav_discover:
                intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, DiscoverActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;
            case R.id.nav_karma:
                intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, KarmaActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_help:
                intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HelpActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_privacy:
                intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, TermsAndPrivacyActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_mode:
                intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HelpModeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                fblogout();
                return;
            default:
                break;
        }

        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        menuItem.setChecked(false);
        //setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }

    private void fblogout() {
        if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        }
        tinyDB.clear();
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        HomeActivity.this.finish();
    }

    public void showGallery(String thumbId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, GalleryActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ID", thumbId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void showImage(String photoId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ImageActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ID", photoId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void showUserProfile(String userId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, UserProfileActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ID", userId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void showComments(String commentId, int position, int row) {
        commentIndex = position;
        r = row;
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, CommentsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ID", commentId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void showLikes(String fiveId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HiFiveActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ID", fiveId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public static void updateComment(boolean b) {
        commented = b;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null,
                    null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);

            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, AddCaptionActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("file", selectedImagePath);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // New code to update comment counter
        if(commented) {
            int numComments = list.get(r).getFeedPhotos().get(commentIndex).getNumComments();
            commented = false;
            list.get(r).getFeedPhotos().get(commentIndex).setNumComments(numComments + 1);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        if(fab.isOpened())
            fab.toggle(true);
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            if(fab.isOpened())
                fab.toggle(true);
            else
                this.moveTaskToBack(true);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }
}
```

Could anyone please help me figure out what's happening? I am getting mad here. I want to use the new support library if possible. Thanks.

**Edit** I have highlighted the code that is causing the problem in support library 23.1.0, if I comment this code out, the app runs perfectly.

**Edit** Here is my manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.galleri5.android" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name=".Galleri5Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LaunchActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SignInActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_in"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.DiscoverTalentsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_discover_talents"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="494aaf4ca421e4bdd34df14063fae3a229af051c" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.UserStudioFansActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_studio_fans"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.UserStudioBookmarksActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_studio_bookmarks"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.UserStudioGalleriesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_studio_galleries"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.UserHiFiveDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_hi_five_details"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.GalleryGridActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gallery_grid"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LeaderboardActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_leaderboard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.GalleryFollowersActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gallery_followers"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.AddNewGalleryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_new_gallery"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.AllGalleriesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_all_galleries"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.AddToNewGalleryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_to_new_gallery"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.TermsAndPrivacyActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_terms_and_privacy"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.WinKarmaDummyActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_win_karma_dummy"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.HelpModeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_help_mode"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.OverallLeaderboardActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.SignInHelpActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please try to isolate your problem

Comment: I have edited the question and highlighted the code which is causing the problem. If I comment out this code, then the problem goes away.

Comment: Attach the debugger and check if navProfile is null at this point

Comment: Will you please post your manifest file ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update**: With the release of Design Support Library **23.1.1**, the following method has been added to address this issue:

```
/**
 * Gets the header view at the specified position.
 *
 * @param index The position at which to get the view from.
 * @return The header view the specified position or null if the position does not exist in this
 * NavigationView.
 */
public View getHeaderView(int index) {
    ...
}
```

You can also retrieve the number of headers, in case you have more than one:

```
/**
 * Gets the number of headers in this NavigationView.
 *
 * @return A positive integer representing the number of headers.
 */
public int getHeaderCount() {
    ...
}
```

In other words, if you use the `headerLayout` attribute, you can now get access to the view using above method:

```
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
ImageView navProfile = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.navProfilePic);
```

Original answer below left intact for background and/or educational purposes.

---

I'm going to make an educated guess and say that the following line is probably inflating a view from your `NavigationView`'s **header** layout:

```
final ImageView navProfile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.navProfilePic);
```

Where the header layout is given to the `NavigationView` using:

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
```

If so, continue reading...

With the 23.1.0 release of the design support library, the internal implementation of `NavigationView` changed to leverage `RecyclerView` (rather than `ListView`). With that change, the header has now become another 'item' in the view, meaning it doesn't become available until *after* the initial layout pass. As such, with your current code, when the `findViewById()` lookup executes, the `RecyclerView` hasn't set up the header yet, and hence the result of the lookup ends up being `null`.

The 'issue' has been [reported](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190226) and the consensus is that getting the header view is going to be exposed with a new method on the `NavigationView` (most likely just called `getHeaderView()`). Until this is rolled out, there are two obvious workarounds I'm aware of.

**Workaround #1:**

Remove `app:headerLayout` and inflate and add the header view manually. Then use the resulting layout to look up any views in the header.

```
View header = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_drawer_header);
ImageView navProfile = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.navProfilePic);
```

**Workaround #2:**

Don't inflate views until *after* the initial layout pass. This can easily be accomplished by posting a `Runnable` to the view's parent's internal message queue, so it gets executed after any pending messages.

```
View parent = (View) mNavigationView.getParent();
parent.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        ImageView navProfile = (ImageView) mNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.navProfilePic);
    }
});
```

Personally, I'd go with #1.

Related:

- [NavigationView get/find header layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194594/navigationview-get-find-header-layout)
- [Android Api 23 Change Navigation View headerLayout textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199764/android-api-23-change-navigation-view-headerlayout-textview)

Comment: You got it exactly right, thanks for this detailed explanation. I would have probably never have found out the cause myself and would have switched back to 23.0.0. Thanks a ton, again.

Answer (score 2):

Now with the 23.1.1 release of the design support library, you can use

```
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
ImageView navProfile = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.navProfilePic);
```