# How to reference an element inside a layout contained in the drawerlayout

Tags: android, textview, drawerlayout

I have a TextView inside a layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_header"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
  android:background="@drawable/avena_nav_drawer"
  android:gravity="bottom"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="@dimen/header_left_padding"
  style="@style/AppTheme">

<!-- Correo de la cuenta -->
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/drawer_email"
  style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/user_email"
  android:textSize="14sp"
  android:textColor="@color/chalk"
  android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, such layout is acting as a header inside my drawerlayout, like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/main_drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/chalk"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/action_menu" />
```

I have been trying to reference my TextView from the Activity that inflates the layout which contains the NavigationView (also tried another tricky/fail-y ways), but it always throws a Null Object Reference.

Could anyone please help me?

EDIT

Here is the logcat:

```
    01-07 22:59:00.149 4284-4284/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.avena.avena, PID: 4284
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.avena.avena/com.avena.avena.dashboard.Dashboard}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.avena.avena.dashboard.Dashboard.onCreate(Dashboard.java:70)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Here is the activity code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    // Set and reference textview inside drawer
    TextView drawer_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_email);

    if (logged) {
        drawer_email.setText(email);
    } else {
        drawer_email.setText("Invitado");
    }

    // Set layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

EDIT 2

Found the right answer here:

[Control view from inside navigation view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33753212/4418038)

Comment: and add the code of your activity also.

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir I have added both logcat and activity code to the original post.

Comment: @ShvetChakra I have edited the original post to include it.

Comment: are the both navigation and textview in the same xml?

Comment: @Mahalakshmi Not quite. The TextView is inside a layout that is being used as header for the NavigationView.

Comment: @SergioMartell activity code has been removed will you add it again and you are not setting any contentview

Comment: then use the whole xml layout name to be added in ur navigation view, use inclde tag for ex:  <include
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/title_height"
        layout="@layout/textviewlayout" />

Comment: @ShvetChakra I put it back.

Comment: you need to put setContentview before you access the TextView inside the layout that your are inflating. As I can see in your current code, you have TextView access call before setcontentview

Comment: First call setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); and then call the findViewByID() method...

Comment: @SergioMartell you have done this research before posting the question. Anyways in future first do all the research about your problem then only post your question.

Comment: @ShvetChakra I did look for it. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You are not inflating your layout, you should add:

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourLayoutNameHere);
```

After:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout... //whatever your inflating code is
        ...

        // Set and reference textview inside drawer
//here use view to access your item
        TextView drawer_email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_email);

        if (logged) {
            drawer_email.setText(email);
        } else {
            drawer_email.setText("Invitado");
        }
```

You can not access any item of the layout without setting the layout or without referencing the view.

So you need to set the view first then access the `textview`

Comment: This does not change it a bit. I get the exact same error.

Comment: if you are inflating it then you need to reference your textview from your view.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your current code it seems that you are trying to access the TextView before you inflate the layout.

Try the following:

```
// Set layout
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

once you call `setContentView`, this API Set the activity content from a layout resource. The resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views to the activity.

call this before you access the `TextView`.

```
TextView drawer_email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_email);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to call

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

and then:

```
TextView drawer_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_email);
//and your rest of code..
```