# NavigationView how to handle dynamic header content

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigationview

I have a pretty standard NavigationView. When i use a static layout in the header like below it works perfect.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>
```

But i want to have a dynamic header so thah i can change it when user logged in etc... So i tried to use a fragment instead of nav_header.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/fragment_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>
```

Can i use a fragment in the headerLayout so i can handle all my logic in the fragment's java file. Or what is the right solution to handle this problem.

Comment: checkout my answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/30660069/3544839 ..here i have used TextView as a root while you can use any viewgroup and once you get object of viewgroup you can easily customize it ..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do that in code by inflating custom layout and set it's header for navigation view.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
View nav_header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header, null);
((TextView) nav_header.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText("UserName");
navigationView.addHeaderView(nav_header);
```

You don't need to set `app:headerLayout` in xml.

Answer (score 12):

You could call the header declared on xml like this:

```
NavigationView navigationView= (NavigationView) findViewById (R.id.navigationView);    
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
```

And then get the views like this:

```
TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Comment: This works when you have set `app:headerLayout` in xml