# Changing Text from header xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an activity in which upon loading I want to update a textfield. That textfield is stored in a header for that activity's layout in an external XML file. When trying to set text pointed at that XML file, I get a `nullpointer` exception.

Here is the activity in which I am using:

```
public class NavDrawerMain extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

//JAC - need to add big search box right at the top of the drawer

//stuff for the user Timeline
private CustomAdapter timelineAdapter;
private ListView timelineList;

private PullToRefreshView mPullToRefreshView;

public static final int REFRESH_DELAY = 2000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_drawer_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    TextView userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drawerUserName);
    userName.setText("test");
```

Here is the layout for that activity:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#e5e5e5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.yalantis.phoenix.PullToRefreshView
        android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/timeListView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

    </com.yalantis.phoenix.PullToRefreshView>


</RelativeLayout>

<include layout="@layout/app_bar_nav_drawer_main"  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_nav_drawer_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_nav_drawer_main_drawer" />
```

and lastly here is the external xml file that houses the `TextView` that I want to change. This file is the header of the activity's xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"  android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="bottom">
android:id="+id/RelativeLayout1"      

<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" android:id="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing" android:text="Android Studio"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="android.studio@android.com" android:id="@+id/drawerUserName" />
```

the textviews id is `drawerUserName`. I had read somewhere that I need to inflate the layout but haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity inflate `header_layout` like this

```
View headerView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.header_layout, null);
TextView userName = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.drawerUserName);
userName.setText("test");
```

Now add it as a HeaderView to NavigationView

```
navigationView.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

And that should be it!

For smiliar question check;
[NavigationView how to handle dynamic header content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580092/navigationview-how-to-handle-dynamic-header-content)

Comment: hmm doing it exacly the way you said it it takes the header layout and places it right on top of everything on that activity... not what I wanted to happen

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? Do you want the 'header' to only appear while loading from pull to refresh? Or is it just in the wrong position?

Comment: ahh okay, so the header is in drawer that opens from the activiity

Comment: hmm thanks for the reply.. not sure its working though.. getting this error:

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: yeah... the textbox is still null:/

Comment: Check my updated answer again :) Changed it to use inflation, apparently it seems like it's not possible to do it without inflating it. My bad. Hope this works for you, unless you solved it already!

Comment: That works. I really appreciate the time you took :) you are awesome. Thanks!