# Change Design Support Navigation View Header Title Programmatically

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, androiddesignsupport

I have a question about Navigation Drawer Header Section Items.
Actually I want to change a TextView in HeaderLayout programatically, here are codes:

```
drawer menu: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="all">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navItem1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_drawer"
        android:title="A"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navItem2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_gallery_drawer"
        android:title="B"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navItem3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_exhibition"
        android:title="C"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navItem4"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_news_drawer"
        android:title="D"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navItem5"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_drawer"
        android:title="E"/>
</group>
```

here is Navigation Header XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="256dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/nav_header" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/nav_header_bar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nav_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="IAMTEXT"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I wanna change this programatically: `android:text="IAMTEXT"`

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want to do. Can you specify the before and after situation clearly? Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Java code:

1. Use `findViewById(R.id.nav_title)` to find the `TextView`
2. use `setText()` to set a text to the `TextView`

For example, in your MainActivity:

```
TextView navTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nav_title);
navTitle.setText("This is a changed string.");
```

Comment: It Works, thanks...sometimes the simple way is the right way.

Comment: What if I want to change the icon too?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using NavigationView

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
```

ok. you can get the header view from the navigation view

```
final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

View headView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

((TextView) headView.findViewById(R.id.nav_title)).setText("New title");
```